# How to bid on like goods, but buy only one, on ebay?

Tags: ebay

Imagine I'm shopping for a model XL-3Q widget on eBay.  There are a half dozen for sale,  all with different end times and conditions.  Yet I want only one.

Is there a way I can chain the bids?  If I fail to win the first listing, I'd like to roll over and bid on the next one.  It might look like this:

```
Auction 1: light scratches: $55 max bid (auction ends in 10 minutes)
Auction 2: perfect condition: $65 max bid (auction ends in 13 minutes)
Auction 3: missing case: $55 max bid
Auction 4: perfect condition: $70 max bid
Auction 5: perfect condition: $75 max bid (auction ends in 2 days)
```

I'll shoot for a bargain with the first auction, but if that fails I'll raise my offer.  This might play out over a few hours or days.  Or maybe I'd just bid $55 for the XL-3Q, and simply try that bid on each auction until I finally get it.

And what's the proper term? Chained bidding, linked bidding, like goods bidding?  Is there a reason eBay does not support it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe some 3rd party eBay "sniper" software (which sometimes run as a web service, rather than desktop software) will do this sort of thing for you. The sniper software is generally used to automate the process of placing a bid in the last few seconds of an auction to increase the chances of a win.

From [techradar's review of "The best free and paid eBay sniper software"](http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/the-best-free-and-paid-ebay-sniper-software-667696) it states that for "[Auction Stealer](http://www.auctionstealer.com/home.cfm)" and "[Auction Sniper](http://www.auctionsniper.com/)":

> ...you can also place your bids in groups, so you can make bids on multiple auctions of the same type of item. When you win one, the others are cancelled.

Comment: More specifically, once you win an auction, the future bids are never placed.  These sites bid only at the last moment, resulting a  flurry of last minute activity on the auction.